# Can a Linux router autoconfigure IPv6 if radvd is running on the same host?

Tags: linux, router, routing, ipv6, radvd

I have a linux gateway router running a 6to4 tunnel and using radvd to broadcast an IPv6 prefix on the local subnet.  Radvd can be configured to automatically pick up the network prefix from the 6to4 interface, however I can't find a way to automatically assign a valid address to the local network interface (eth0).

For example, if my 6to4 inteface is autoconfigures to `2002:4185:9dd4::1/16`, then eth0 needs an address of `2002:4185:9dd4:dead:<whatever>/64` (where 'dead' is the local subnet I configured in radvd.conf).  With radvd running on the local machine, is there any way to force linux to autoconfigure eth0?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer:  On a system that you are running `radvd` on, you want to configure the interface using the same method as you use to configure `radvd`; if `radvd.conf` is statically generated, then so should your local Ethernet interface's IPv6 address be statically generated.  But, all is not lost; read on for more detail.

What you can do is use a small shell script to configure both.  Let's say for a moment that you have a dynamically assigned global IPv4 address, **and** this is the only IPv4 address on your interface; you can use the following shell script snippet to obtain the IPv6 /48 prefix (note: code adapted from [ARIN](http://www.getipv6.info/index.php/Linux_or_BSD_6to4_Relays):

```
IPV4=$(ip addr ls eth0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -f1 -d/)
PARTS=`echo $IPV4 | tr . ' '`
PREFIX48=`printf "2002:%02x%02x:%02x%02x" $PARTS`
```

Now, you have the /48 prefix; getting a /64 prefix is simple enough, since you can just append it to the `$PREFIX48` variable.

Now, all that would be left for you to do is write the script that writes out the network interface configuration and radvd configuration (presumably, from a template for each of them) and make that script run before your network configuration does.  I'll not be including that code here as I do not know what distribution you are using, and it differs depending on that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: or:
PREFIX48=$(ipv6calc --action conv6to4 --in ipv4 $IPV4 --out ipv6)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. But if your MAC address and the prefix you use don't change, why not statically configure the interface with the address that would otherwise come from auto-assignment?

If your MAC address or prefix do regularly change, I'm curious to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

What's your router running?  If it's a full-blown distribution like Gentoo, OpenRC has a `/etc/conf.d/net:6to4_suffix` setting, and if [#357929](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=357929) gets fixed the way that's been proposed, Debian will have a `/etc/network/interfaces:6to4subnet` setting too.

Otherwise, I would just set the address manually.  A script on my router contains something like this:

```
IDEV=br0
ODEV=vlan2
WANIP=`ip -4 addr show dev "$ODEV"|awk '/inet /{print$2}'|cut -d/ -f1`
V6PREFIX=`printf '2002:%02x%02x:%02x%02x' ${WANIP//./ }`
V6NET=16
GW=192.88.99.1

ip tunnel add 6to4 mode sit remote any local "$IP" ttl 255 dev "$ODEV"
ip link set 6to4 up
ip addr add "$V6PREFIX::1/$V6NET" dev 6to4
ip addr add "$V6PREFIX:1::1/$((V6NET+48))" dev "$IDEV"
ip route add 2000::/3 via "::$GW" dev 6to4 metric 1
```

I guess you want `$V6PREFIX:dead::1/$((V6NET+48))` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following configuration in your /etc/network/interfaces file on your host running Radvd.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

"auto" here means using SLAAC for interface eth0, which will solicit IPv6 configuration from Radvd in the same way as other clients.